# Convert Vector field marker to line shapefile

Tags: qgis, bearing

I am using QGIS. I have a set of data with bearings from set points. I have used vector field markers to show them as lines from the point in the direction of the bearing but I want to have this as a line shapefile so I can manipulate the data and identify intersections with other files.

I am quite new to QGIS so it may be easy to sort this in a way I haven't noticed, but I couldn't see it and I didn't find a question on here where it has been answered.

Comment: I would want to just use a standard length for all of them. 1 km or something like that